# Runnable Jar -> help-function for command line arguments

Tags: java, jar

I exported My application as a Runnable jar. The user has always to pass 4 arguments to execute the application. Now I need something like a help function to provide an information about the specific arguments. But I dont know how to realize that in a proper and clean way. Should i work with arguments again and check if the user pass "-help"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propper way is to check it at `main` when it receive the arguments

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Check how many arguments were passed in
    if(args.length != 4)
    {
        System.out.println("Proper Usage is: java program filename arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Extend the `println` as far as you want to give further info and better user experience.

If you **ALSO** want to accept `-help` as argument:

```
if(Arrays.asList(args).contains("-help") || args.length != 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its advisable that you should use `Scanner` class because it does the same thing as command line arguments does but here while running the jar you can prompt the message like

press `H for Help`. After getting it with `nextLine()` you can stipulate it with loading a help description file into the memory and show it into the terminal.

or if you want to stick with command line than check the size of command line arguments and prompt for Help response.

Comment: This was actually my first idea, but this is unfortunately not desired

Comment: @MarryS thats why I said "Advisable" anyways thanks for upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes the best way to provide information to the user about the arguments is two have a -help type command. Also it is useful to print information about the correct usage of the program if the incorrect number (or type) of arguments are given.

Example: java -jar Runnable.jar

```
Help:
  4 Arguments are required for the program to run.
  The first argument is X and is needed for Y.
  Also, if you want the program to run in debug mode, 
  add the -debug flag to the end of the program
```